# Parsing FIND MY IPHONE?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

As you probably know there's that think called "FIND MY IPHONE" ( www.me.com ), that enables you to see your phones location on a google map in real time.

Yet I was thinking if there would be any way to make a PHP file that would
1. run automatically every, say, 15 minutes.
2. pass cookies with my username/password to me.com
3. retrieve the lat/long coordinates from it and save them into a database.

that way I would have a history of my phone's location.

how would you suggest doing it, can a php file pass cookies or is there something else needed? and how to retrieve those lat/long coordinates that are already shown on a google map?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the origin of Lat/Lon.. is this coming from the iPhone within some sort of application you control ?

Comment: when I login me.com it somehow requests the coordinates from my iphones OS 4.2 , I don't have any control over it. :) hacking into this process, I believe, would be much harder then simply getting the coordinates from the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

If there aren't any limitations to this service you might be interested in reading about php cURL. Link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

You can use cookies and login just like a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

cUrl is the best solution for your request, you can find some useful stuff here
[link text](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-things-to-do-with-curl)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [there](http://linktoapp.com/imapmyrun) [is an](http://linktoapp.com/runkeeper) [app for that](http://linktoapp.com/itrail) ;)